# Conflicting enum values java

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, enums, runtime-error, ignite

I have 2 enums defined as below in 2 separate files:
`MyErrorCodes.java`

```
@Getter
public enum MyErrorCodes implements ErrorCode {
    ERROR1(90, 1, 01),
    ERROR2(90, 1, 02),
    ERROR3(90, 1, 03),
    ERROR4(90, 1, 04),
    ERROR5(90, 1, 05);
    ....
}
```

`ErrorCategory.java`

```
public class ErrorCategory {
@AllArgsConstructor
    public enum ErrorCodes {
        EXECUTION_ERROR("execution.error", "Error in executing {0}.", INTERNAL_ERROR,
                             MyErrorCodes.ERROR1),
        DESERIALIZATION_ERROR("...", "...",BAD_REQUEST_ERROR, MyErrorCodes.ERROR2),
        DEFAULT_INTERNAL_ERROR("...", "...", INTERNAL_ERROR, MyErrorCodes.ERROR3),
        INVALID_RESPONSE("...", "...", INTERNAL_ERROR, MyErrorCodes.ERROR4),
        MAPPING_ERROR("...", "...", INTERNAL_ERROR, MyErrorCodes.ERROR5);
   }
}
```

At Runtime I am getting error:

```
Conflicting enum values. Name 'ERROR4' uses ordinal value (4) that is also used for name 'MAPPING_ERROR'
```

`ERROR4` is 4th element in enum#1 while `MAPPING_ERROR` is 5th element in the enum#2.
Then Why am I getting conflict error when they are completely different enums?

P.S. the interface implemented by enum#1 looks like this:

```
public interface ErrorCode {
    int getErrorCode();
    String getKey();

}
```

stacktrace:

````
at io.opentracing.contrib.concurrent.TracedRunnable.run(TracedRunnable.java:30)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
   
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Conflicting enum values. Name 'ERROR4' uses ordinal value (4) that is also used for name 'MAPPING_ERROR'
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.mergeEnumValues(BinaryUtils.java:2538)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.mergeMetadata(BinaryUtils.java:1028)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.BinaryMetadataTransport.requestMetadataUpdate(BinaryMetadataTransport.java:211)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.addMeta(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:606)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl$1.addMeta(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerUserClassDescriptor(BinaryContext.java:828)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerDescriptor(BinaryContext.java:784)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerClass(BinaryContext.java:581)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerClass(BinaryContext.java:556)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteEnum(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:829)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeEnumField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1323)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:670)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157)
    ... 115 common frames omitted
    ```
````

Comment: By the way, do you understand that a leading zero makes a numeric literal [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)?

Comment: By the way, naming your enum in the singular makes its usage more intuitive. `ErrorCode` rather than `ErrorCodes`, `MyErrorCode` rather than `MyErrorCodes`.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code calling `org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.mergeEnumValues`. I’m voting to close for a lack of details for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here is what we did and found out regarding the issue:

We were using [ignite cluster](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/clustering) for our deployment purpose, we updated the ignite version from 6 to 7 and that solved the issue.

Ignite caches the enum values, so When we introduce new enum values we should add to the end to increment the ordinal to avoid conflicts in future or clear the cache.